# The graph of Borel measurable function whose range is a separable metrisable space

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

> If $Y$ is separable and $f : X \to Y$ is Borel measurable, then the graph of
>   $f$ is Borel.

On page 14, Lemma 2.3, (iii) of this [online note](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math512/dst.pdf), given, $\{U_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$, a basis for the topology of  a metrisable space $Y$, the graph of $f$ is:

[image]

I can't see why this formula represents the graph of $f$. It seems to me it's an empty set.

Comment: Is $Y$ assumed to be metrisable? Otherwise, why would it even have a countable basis?

Comment: @tomasz: Yes, it is metrisable.

Comment: I spelled this out for the graph of a function with values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/286625/49437) maybe it helps understanding where this comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right; it's empty, as $U_n$ cover $Y$.

It's a typo, most likely meant to be
$$\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty \left( \{(x,y)\mid y\notin U_n\} \cup \{(x,y) \mid x\in f^{-1}[U_n]\} \right)$$